# Why this class doesn't make error?

Tags: c++, class, private, public

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Class ITEM{
private:
    int cnt;

public:
    ITEM(){}

    void func(ITEM a){
        a.cnt = 10;
    }
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

I assume that red line will make the error.
because 'a.cnt' value is private value.
I learned that private value must be modified inner of class.

Comment: Why would you expect an error? Class member functions have access to private members.

Comment: Member function is inner of class, right?

Comment: it's not classes that make errors, it's programmers.

Comment: but, ITEM a is external object. so is it impossible to access directly to a.cnt in function 'func' ?

Comment: @user3504418 You can pass itself back, (even it maks nosense,) it's impossible to distinguish at compile time. e.g. `void func(ITEM& a) { a.cnt = 10; } ITEM item; item.func(item);`

Answer (score 1):

```
void func(A a){
    a.cnt = 10; //valid
}
```

notice that function is inside the class, so it becomes it member and class member functions have access to private members.

Note that it is being modified inner of the class ITEM using a member function,which is perfectly valid